# understanding thread pool when an aggregator is used

Tags: spring-integration

I am trying to understand at a high level how the thread allocation happens within the spring integration flow especially when an aggreagtor is used. To provide some context my flow looks something like this

poll files from a directory
use an executor channel to received polled files
aggregate polled files until some criteria is met
release aggregated files to a subsequent channel which processes all aggregated files
split files 
archive individual files

the main goal in this configuration is the detach the polling process from the subsequent steps in the flow. I want to be able to continue to poll and load files while the existing files are being processed. All that works fine with using an executor channel but once the thread pool limit is reached and if lets say the poller thread ends up getting stuck because of CALLER_RUNS rejection policy then I have to wait until this thread is completed before it can return to polling more files.

Okay so going back to my real question which is to understand how threads are allocated in such a flow. So poller retieves a file, passes it to the executor channel which uses a dispatcher and therefore creates a new thread to handle the incoming file. Now once this file gets stuck in the aggregator what happens to this thread. Is the thread completed/closed because the file has reached its current final destination.

And then once the aggregator limit is reached and all files are emitted to the next channel I am assuming that happens in a new/single thread but then when we use a splitter it then creates a new thread for every split file. Is that correct.

I am sorry if this is a bit confusing. I am really just understand the process a little bit better because what I dont like about this setup (my configuration) is that almost every time the flow gets stuck at the step after the aggregator which is the time consuming step since its processing all aggregated files .. most of the its the CALLER_RUNS that ends up executing the time consuming step .. which then essentially stops the polling process until this time consuming step is done.

I will also post my configuration xml but basically I am hoping that with better understanding of the thread allocation process I might be able to tune this a little more and not make the aggregated files processing step a bottleneck.

```
<!-- Poll files from landing zone directory -->
<int-file:inbound-channel-adapter id="files" directory="${lz.dir.${ft}}" filename-regex=".*\.txt$">
    <int:poller fixed-delay="3000" max-messages-per-poll="10"  />
</int-file:inbound-channel-adapter>

<int:bridge input-channel="files" output-channel="sourceFiles" />

<!-- Dispatch retrieved files -->
<int:channel id="sourceFiles">
    <int:dispatcher task-executor="executor" />
</int:channel>

<!-- Move files to source directory -->
<int:service-activator  input-channel="sourceFiles"
                        output-channel="sourceFilesProcessed" 
                        ref="moveToSource" 
                        method="move" />

<int:channel id="sourceFilesProcessed" />

<!-- Aggregate at source -->
<int:aggregator id="filesBuffered" 
                input-channel="sourceFilesProcessed"
                output-channel="stagedFiles"
                release-strategy-expression="size() >= 500 and !@moveToStageAndTarget.isRunning()" 
                correlation-strategy-expression="'mes-group'" 
                expire-groups-upon-completion="true" 
                />

<int:channel id="stagedFiles" />

<!-- Process aggregated source files -->
<int:chain input-channel="stagedFiles">
    <!-- Move stage files to target -->
    <int:service-activator  ref="moveToStageAndTarget" method="move" />

    <!-- Split files back into individual file -->
    <int:splitter />

    <!-- Archice each file -->
    <int:service-activator ref="archiveFiles" method="archive" />           
</int:chain>    

<task:executor id="executor" pool-size="100" queue-capacity="0" rejection-policy="CALLER_RUNS" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. It's bad to use `queue-capacity="0"`. Take a look, please, to the JavaDocs of [`ThreadPoolTaskExecutor`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.1.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/concurrent/ThreadPoolTaskExecutor.html#setQueueCapacity-int-).
   So, your **sticking** is really around `SynchronousQueue`
2. It is recommended to use `ExecutorChannel` as an output for `<splitter>`, as far as it produces several `Messages`, In your case now they all are processed within the same `Thread` one by one.
3. Aggregator does not depend of thread, but there is need to keep in mind that it **release** a group within that `Thread`, whose `Message` says to `release-strategy` `true`. So, it is an another case why you get **sticking**.

Comment: Not sure how queue capacity would help coz if I lets say change the max pool size to 50 and queue capacity to 50 then the end result will be the same as max pool being 100. For splitter it makes sense but I think it might be ok in my case to let a single thread handle all files sequentially from a splitter because that step is pretty quick and I might as well leave the thread pool used by othher processes in the flow.

Comment: Another advice change the output-channel of `aggregator` to the `queue`. Anyway `SynchronousQueue` is bad. It waits for `offer`, before another thread won't do `pull`

Comment: by setting output channel for aggregator being queue, how will that be different/better .. i mean essentially there is only one message being sent out by the aggregator (the collection of messages) .. just trying to understand ur point. Ill try changing the queue capacity to see how it behaves. Thanks

Comment: One more time: aggregator doesn't depend on Thread and send its result withing some on enclosed thread. As far it is one from your thread-pool and there is no deviation in the downstream flow, all work will be done within that thread. But here is an issue around `SynchronousQueue`. That's why you polling task is stick

Comment: sorry i was talking about splitter output channel being executor not the aggregator but i get the general idea ill try playing with queue size to see what works better. thanks